# How can I load div content from html pages into a div on main page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list/link on a page
When I click a list/link item,
I want to load div content from other pages into a div on the main page.
I known that this can be done by hardcoding like below.

```html
<div id="main1">
  <ul>      
     <li onclick="load();return false;">Home</li>
     <li onclick="load();return false;">Work</li>    
     <li onclick="load();return false;">Contact</li>                
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="main2"> </div>
```

```js
function load() {
  $("#main2").load("home.html #title");
}
```

Instead of this is it possible to pass the .html in as a parameter?
Something like

```html
<li onclick="load('home.html');return false;">Home</li>
```

```js
function load(url) {
   $("#main2").load( + url + "#title");
}
```

Thanks for any help and apologies for the noob question :)

Comment: Have you tried to execute your code ? Any Errors occured ? In fact, yes you can pass an parameter to javascript-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be:

```
function load(url) {
    $("#main2").load( url + " #title");
}
```

but I would advise against inline JS. I would use something like:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#main1 li').on('click', function() {
        $('#main2').load( $(this).data('url') + ' ' + $(this).data('target') );
    });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main1">
        <ul>        
            <li data-url="home.html" data-target="#title">Home</li>
            <li data-url="work.html" data-target="#title">Work</li>     
            <li data-url="contact.html" data-target="#title">Contact</li>                
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="main2"> </div>
```

**References:**

1. [**.load() | jQuery API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) -- see loading **Loading Page Fragments** section

Comment: thats excat the same as in the question, there's an unnecessary "+" before url

Comment: @empiric, understood. I was still working on a recommendation.

Comment: Looks way better now ;-)

Comment: Thank you folks , i had tired removing the "+" before posting , it was the extra space in the String that i didnt see url + "#title" as opposed to  url + " #title"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and you almost have it. Just lose the extra `+` in your `load()` function, and add a space before `#title` (to match the your correct earlier example):

```
 function load(url) {
   $("#main2").load( url + " #title" );
 }
```

Comment: You also added a necessary `(space)` character, but didn't mention doing so :)